# Network list is unresponsive after waking up (Win 8)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

I recently bought my laptop, an HP 2000t with Win8, a couple of months ago.  After I wake my laptop from sleep mode, it has trouble connecting to the internet.  It has worked a couple of times on its own, but when it doesn't connect, it simply will not.  Clicking the taskbar icon will show the clicking animation but nothing happens.  My Network List will not show up.  Tried running the troubleshooter and it could not identify the problem.  I tried toggling my airplane mode key on the keyboard, but the button is completely unresponsive and remains "off". There seems to be no other way to connect other than a reboot.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with either the network adapter or its drivers. Have you checked for driver updates on HP's site? Since it's a recent purchase, did you try contacting them?

Comment: I am thinking it is a driver issue, because my roommates can all connect without a problem.  I have not yet tried to contact them (not a fan of generic customer support, I always take it as a last resort option) I've gone to the Software & Driver page on the HP website, after running its scan to detect my product.  It has a list of about 7 different network drivers.  How do I know which one I need?

Comment: Maybe you can see which of the 7 matches with what's mentioned in Device Manager?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb question, but is there a Wi-Fi light?  My HP dv7 laptop has it on the F12 key that's orange when the radio is off and white when it's on.  (Perhaps that's what your model refers to as the airplane mode key?)  On my Dell D620, the light is on the screen hinge and is controlled by a slide switch on the left side of the case near the keyboard.

If the indicator light remains unresponsive after operating the key, it sounds like a driver problem, but recent drivers (since Win 7 at least) don't normally have problems with suspend/resume.  It's a real longshot, but you could try reloading the driver.

Comment: Yes it has a light.  The key always works, unless I am having the problem with the network list not showing up, in which it doesn't respond.

Comment: The network list not showing up is a consequence of the radio not being enabled, not a cause.  If the laptop can't use the radio it can't see any SSIDs, so the list of what it *can* see will naturally be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VirtualBox installed? The "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver" can cause it.

As a workaround, open the network adapter setting, uncheck the driver, wait until this is finished and now select the driver again. This also worked for me in Windows 7.